# I would like to get process name,process id ,Process Path,Product Name Window Title

Tags: visual-c++

- how to get process information like this format 
  my develop tools is visual c++ 2008
  I would like to get process name,process id ,Process Path,Product Name  Window Title
  but i don't know how to connect those information toghter

[image]

Comment: Do you want to enumerate all tasks, and show this kind of information for all of them, or do you have some particular task in mind? If you have a particular task in mind, how are you going to identify it to start with?

Comment: I would like to get process name,process path,process id ,product name ,and process full path,process window's title

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want this information about youself (the running process).

To get the process name and path use the [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get the full path and use the last element in the path as the process name.

To get the process id use the [GetCurrentProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

To get the window title use the [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  function.